# Convert CSV to Excel Windows Phone 8

Tags: excel, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8

with windows phone 8 I need to be able to open a CSV file in Excel using C#. Their is an app on the market now called Excel Extensions that converts the csv file locally.

I have tired converting the CSV file using open office XML but that didn't work. and I want to do it locally so no web services.

Anyone know how I can convert the CSV file to Excel on the Windows Phone 8 platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**THEORY**

You have a two distinct options: (1) doing most of the work on the WP8 client (2) or doing most of the work on a remote server.

For **option #2 of using a remote server**: Expose a WCF service that takes in the CSV file, parses the CSV to find its logical 2D table structure, use [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) to save a new XLSX file and return that to the client. This option is the most straightforward but also requires network connectivity and a hosted server.

For **option #1 of not using a remote server**: read the CSV file, copy the CSV data into to an XLSX file, [save the XLSX into IsoStore and launch excel with that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702643/how-can-we-create-write-and-read-an-excel-file-for-windows-phone-8). I've written about this topic in the past @  [How can we create, write and read an excel file for Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702643/how-can-we-create-write-and-read-an-excel-file-for-windows-phone-8)

One thing you'll have to do quite **a lot of work is writing a XLSX file in pure WP7 C#**. You'll either have to convert [3rd party](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) [libraries](https://nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml) that write XLSX to support WP7/WP8, or convert [simple end-to-end C# code samples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208075/How-to-read-and-write-xlsx-Excel-2007-file-Part-I) to WP7/WP8.  Both aren't simple. Converting ClosedXML is possible but DocumentFormat.OpenXml's dependency on WPF's WindowsCore is a problem. Another option is to write your own OpenXML C# implementation like Chris Klug [did here](http://chris.59north.com/post/OpenXML-2b-Silverlight-using-a-little-library.aspx) for Word OpenXML on Silverlight and was [ported to WP7](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/01/13/105441.aspx) later on. The key is using OpenXML specification for your advantage.

---

**LIVE CODE SAMPLE**

For example, looking at  Chris Klug's [Silverlight Excel OpenXML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2010/04/01/8360.aspx) article it's possible to take his code for *[Ag.OpenXML](http://agopenxml.codeplex.com/)* and *[OpenXML.Silverlight.Spreadsheet](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2010/04/01/8360.aspx)* port those to WP8 and then simply invoke them. I did just that. Here's how to get that experimental source code and get started:

1) Download and unzip @  http://JustinAngel.net/Storage/OpenXML.Silverlight.Spreadsheet.WP8.zip

2) Add a reference to the csproj, or to the DLLs OpenXML.Silverlight.Spreadsheet.WP8.dll &  SharpZipLib.dll from "OpenXML.Silverlight.Spreadsheet.WP8\Bin\Debug".

3) Add the following code snippet that saves a SpreedsheetDocument file into your app's WP8 IsoStore and then launches it in Word using WP8 app2app file associations.

```cs
private async void SaveXlsxToIsoStoreAndLaunchInExcel(SpreadsheetDocument doc)
{
    using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (isoStore.FileExists("myFile.xlsx"))
            isoStore.DeleteFile("myFile.xlsx");

        using (var s = isoStore.CreateFile("myFile.xlsx"))
        using (IStreamProvider storage = new ZipStreamProvider(s))
        {
            doc.Save(storage);
        }

        Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(
            await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myFile.xlsx"));
    }
}
```

4) Invoke the above code snippet with Chris's sample document:

```cs
private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SpreadsheetDocument doc = new SpreadsheetDocument();
    doc.ApplicationName = "SilverSpreadsheet";
    doc.Creator = "Chris Klug";
    doc.Company = "Intergen";

    SharedStringDefinition str1 = doc.Workbook.SharedStrings.AddString("Column 1");
    SharedStringDefinition str2 = doc.Workbook.SharedStrings.AddString("Column 2");
    SharedStringDefinition str3 = doc.Workbook.SharedStrings.AddString("Column 3");

    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[0].Cells[0].SetValue(str1);
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[0].Cells[1].SetValue(str2);
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[0].Cells[2].SetValue(str3);

    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[1].Cells[0].SetValue("Value 1");
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[1].Cells[1].SetValue(1);
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[1].Cells[2].SetValue(1001);

    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[2].Cells[0].SetValue("Value 2");
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[2].Cells[1].SetValue(2);
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[2].Cells[2].SetValue(1002);

    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[3].Cells[0].SetValue("Value 3");
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[3].Cells[1].SetValue(3);
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[3].Cells[2].SetValue(1003);

    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[4].Cells[0].SetValue("Value 4");
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[4].Cells[1].SetValue(4);
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[4].Cells[2].SetValue(1004);

    TablePart table = doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.AddTable("My Table", "My Table", doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[0].Cells[0], doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[4].Cells[2]);
    table.TableColumns[0].Name = str1.String;
    table.TableColumns[1].Name = str2.String;
    table.TableColumns[2].Name = str3.String;

    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.AddColumnSizeDefinition(0, 2, 20);

    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[5].Cells[1].SetValue("Sum:");
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[5].Cells[2].Formula = "SUM(" + doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[1].Cells[2].CellName + ":" + doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[4].Cells[2].CellName + ")";


    SaveXlsxToIsoStoreAndLaunchInExcel(doc);
}
```

5) When running this code snippet we can see the following warning popup and then the excel spreadsheet. Feel free to improve upon my hasty Silverlight-->WP8 port and remove that warning.

[image: Excel WP8 open with the file we just created]
[image: Corrupt file warning on WP8 Excel]