# How to read write xls, docs and csv file in windows phone 8 application

Tags: c#, excel, windows-phone-7, csv, windows-phone-8

I am trying to develop an application where user can create, read and write excel, word and csv files. I have done lots of googling but still I have not reached there. Is there any third party library(paid/free) or .dll available that can help me to read/write word,excel or csv file in windows phone 8 application. Could any one give idea where to start from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702643/how-can-we-create-write-and-read-an-excel-file-for-windows-phone-8 might give a pointer