# Read/import existing Excel file programmatically (cell-by-cell) in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app to READ/WRITE Excel files. I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761974/how-to-read-write-xls-docs-and-csv-file-in-windows-phone-8-application) here about this and the comment provided and many other links led me to [OpenXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702643/how-can-we-create-write-and-read-an-excel-file-for-windows-phone-8).

All of this got me good on how to *create* an Excel file and how to launch it. But now I am stuck at very basic of these all i.e. How to *read* an existing Excel file (probably created outside using MS Excel) cell-by-cell i.e. I want to access each cells and their values through my code. In the openXML thing I did this:

```
Stream localFile = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/ReadExcel;component/jai.xlsx"
                                                    ,UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
localFile.CopyTo(ms);

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDoc =
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(localFile, true);
{
    var a = spreadsheetDoc.Package;
    // Do work here
}
```

But it gives me error:

```
The type 'System.IO.Packaging.Package' is defined in an assembly that is not 
referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0
```

So basically I am stuck at this `WindowsBase.dll`. I tried all various ways to import an assembly i.e. unblock and all, but nothing works.

So all I want to do is to programmatically access the content of an existing Excel file in my code cell-by-cell.

Please help or suggest whether it is even possible as of now in WP8.

Comment: Hm, according to the exception you just need to add the reference to the assembly WindowsBase. Have you tried to add this reference and set "Copy local" = true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following method to read cells from an xlsx Excel file on Windows Phone 8:

1. Add the [Microsoft Compression library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.compression) to your project using NuGet
2. Adapt the code sample from the [developer network](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4fce4765-2d05-4a2b-8d0a-6219e87f3307/reading-excel-file-using-c-in-winrt-platform) to your needs - it shows how to read cells from an Excel file (and it needs the Compression lib)

Since I already extended the code a bit to handle **empty columns** and **empty files** properly you can also use my code:

```
public class ExcelReader
{
    List<string> _sharedStrings;

    List<Dictionary<string, string>> _derivedData;

    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> DerivedData
    {
        get
        {
            return _derivedData;
        }
    }
    List<string> _header;

    public List<string> Headers { get { return _header; } }

    // e.g. cellID = H2 - only works with up to 26 cells
    private int GetColumnIndex(string cellID)
    {
        return cellID[0] - 'A';
    }

    public void StartReadFile(Stream input)
    {
        ZipArchive z = new ZipArchive(input, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
        var worksheet = z.GetEntry("xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml");
        var sharedString = z.GetEntry("xl/sharedStrings.xml");

        // get shared string
        _sharedStrings = new List<string>();
        // if there is no content the sharedStrings will be null
        if (sharedString != null)
        {
            using (var sr = sharedString.Open())
            {
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
                _sharedStrings =
                    (
                    from e in xdoc.Root.Elements()
                    select e.Elements().First().Value
                    ).ToList();
            }
        }

        // get header
        using (var sr = worksheet.Open())
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
            // get element to first sheet data
            XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";
            XElement sheetData = xdoc.Root.Element(xmlns + "sheetData");

            _header = new List<string>();
            _derivedData = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

            // worksheet empty?
            if (!sheetData.Elements().Any())
                return;
            // build header first
            var firstRow = sheetData.Elements().First();
            // full of c
            foreach (var c in firstRow.Elements())
            {
                // the c element, if have attribute t, will need to consult sharedStrings
                string val = c.Elements().First().Value;
                if (c.Attribute("t") != null)
                {
                    _header.Add(_sharedStrings[Convert.ToInt32(val)]);
                } else
                {
                    _header.Add(val);
                }

            }

            // build content now
            foreach (var row in sheetData.Elements())
            {
                // skip row 1
                if (row.Attribute("r").Value == "1")
                    continue;
                Dictionary<string, string> rowData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                // the "c" elements each represent a column
                foreach (var c in row.Elements())
                {
                    var cellID = c.Attribute("r").Value; // e.g. H2

                    // each "c" element has a "v" element representing the value
                    string val = c.Elements().First().Value;
                    // a string? look up in shared string file
                    if (c.Attribute("t") != null)
                    {
                        rowData.Add(_header[GetColumnIndex(cellID)], _sharedStrings[Convert.ToInt32(val)]);
                    } else
                    {
                        // number
                        rowData.Add(_header[GetColumnIndex(cellID)], val);
                    }
                }
                _derivedData.Add(rowData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works for simple Excel files having one work sheet and some text and number cells. It assumes there is a header row.

Usage is as follows:

```
var excelReader = new ExcelReader();
excelReader.StartReadFile(excelStream);
```

After reading `excelReader.Headers` contains the header names, `excelReader.DerivedData` contains the rows. Each row is a `Dictionary` having the header as key and the data as value. Empty cells won't be in there.

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thanx Heinrich. But its too late for me I alreday got the solution. Any way I mark as upvote/accept. Thanx man.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use the official OpenXML SDK by Microsoft. The reason is exactly the exception you already ran into. WP8 does not have the System.IO.Packaging namespace available which is required to extract/compress the zip-based xlsx file format. Adding WindowsBase.dll won't work either because it is not compiled for WP8.

After googling for quite some time in the last two years about this the only 3 solutions that I know are (despite developing Excel support from zero by your own :) ):

1. Use the Ag.OpenXML open source project which you can find on http://agopenxml.codeplex.com/ . The source repository contains an implementation to write an Excel file (the downloadable package only contains Word export). I use this in my WP8 app for quite some time and it works well despite the lack of a lot of features. Unfortunately, this package is not maintained anymore since 2011. However, it might be a good start for you.
2. Use the commercial libraries of ComponentOne https://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWindowsPhone/
3. Use the commercial libraries of Syncfusion http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone