# how can I open excel table in WP8 App

Tags: excel, windows-phone-8

How can I open an excel table with Windows Phone 8 App. I get a file bin (byte[]) from a service.

Any ideas?
Thanks Michael

Comment: Is this the one you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800122/read-import-existing-excel-file-programmatically-cell-by-cell-in-windows-phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy! With this 3 lines you can lauch each file on Windows phone 8.x

```
            StorageFolder attachmentFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(ViewModelLocator.ATTACHMENT_FOLDER, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            StorageFile storageFile = await attachmentFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(storageFile);
```

If you use LaunchFileAsync API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701471.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 , then the file will be opened by an app that has registered to handle the pdf file extension – probably the PDF Reader app. But if no suitable app is installed, the user gets taken to the store to choose one to install.

Works on WP8.0 and 8.1.

Thanks to Andy Wigley!